# Can I change the Unity Launcher transparency?

Tags: unity, launcher, transparency

Is it possible to change the background opacity of the Unity Launcher?

[image: Transparent Background]

I see you can change the panel opacity, but then the launcher clashes with the panel.

Answer (score 15):

From the terminal, you can use:

```
gsettings get org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ launcher-opacity
```

to get the current value for launcher opacity and

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ launcher-opacity X
```

to set the launcher opacity to `X`. `X` must be between 0 and 1.

<sub>P:S This way is preferred over any other method that used dconf directly.</sub>

See also:

- [How can I adjust the transparency of the Status Bar (top panel)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70910/how-can-i-adjust-the-transparency-of-the-top-panel)

Comment: worked on 16.04

Answer (score 5):

#### For 11.10 and 12.04

There's an option to do this in `ccsm`:

[image: Screenshot of ccsm with launcher opacity setting]

([Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/08/unity-oneiric-changes-august/))

Answer (score 3):

## 13.10

If you're running 13.10 you can use Unity Tweak Tool.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Open the "Launcher" category, from there you can use the "Transparency level" slider to adjust the launcher's transparency.

[image]

You can also change the launcher's color.

Comment: This does not remove the transparency once the dash is open. Works only on the launcher bar. (at least on 16.04)

Answer (score 2):

#### 11.04

You can use unity-df (a patched launcher)

> Unity-df gives you options to change launcher's color and transparency AND it lets you place launcher at any place you want it.

Download Links

[32-Bit](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/566323/temp/unity-df_0.2.47-0ubuntu5_i386.deb)  [64-Bit](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/566323/temp/unity-df_0.2.47-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb)

[Source](http://omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/five-neat-changes-in-todays-unity-update/#comment-176288444)

Comment: I'm getting this error when I attempt to install it. "Error: Breaks existing package 'unity' that conflict: 'netbook-launcher'. But the '/home/alex/Desktop/unity-df_0.2.47-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb' provides it via: 'indicator-renderer,netbook-launcher'"

Comment: @Alaukik Forgot to link your name when replying to you. See my other comment.

Comment: @Spacecraft i have not made this you should try and contact _artem_ on twitter (http://twitter.com/artemeas)

Comment: @Alaukik Artem told me on twitter that he is not the developer of this package.

Comment: The original source is http://tehnoblog.net/2011/04/kak-pomenyat-raspolozhenie-paneli-unity-v-ubuntu-11-04/ If Google gets the translation right it's a april fool hoax.

Comment: I've removed @Alaukik's post as the answer until I know for sure if this is legitimate or not.