# Error when installing patched Unity launcher

Tags: unity, 11.04, launcher, transparency

I'm  getting the following error when I try to install "unity-df", which is a patched launcher for Unity that allows you to further customize the launcher. 
`Error: Breaks existing package 'unity' that conflict: 'netbook-launcher'. But the '/home/alex/unity-df_0.2.47-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb' provides it via: 'indicator-renderer,netbook-launcher'`

"Unity-df" links
[32 bit](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/566323/temp/unity-df_0.2.47-0ubuntu5_i386.deb)
[64 bit](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/566323/temp/unity-df_0.2.47-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb)
[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33043/can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-transparency)

Is this an outdated package, or is it for the Maverick version of Unity? And does anyone know who the author of this package is?

Answer (score 1):

Installing a package if you don't know the author is a very bad idea as during installation the package has full root access to your machine.

The package provides the virtual package "netbook-launcher", but the installed package "unity" conflicts with "netbook-launcher". So you can't have both installed at the same time.

Comment: @ Florian Well I don't know who the original author is, but this package seems to be fairly popular and I figured if there was something wrong with it someone would have said so. Anyways, I've seen other manage to get this installed on 11.04 - I think. Isn't this supposed to replace current packages, not install alongside them?

Comment: The original source is http://tehnoblog.net/2011/04/kak-pomenyat-raspolozhenie-paneli-unity-v-ubuntu-11-04/ If Google gets the translation right it's a april fool hoax.

Comment: That's so weird. I hope it isn't a joke. Someone linked that solution to me when I asked on this website about customizing the launcher. If that's true I'll need to go flag that answer. Thanks.