# Is there a way to set Unity 3d's dock/launcher to be completely opaque like Unity 2d's?

Tags: unity, icons, transparency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change the Unity Launcher transparency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33043/can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-transparency)

Unity 3d icons and launcher:

[image]

Unity 2d icons and launcher:

[image]
In unity 2d, the icons looks darker than in 3d. In 3d, the icons have a clearer color to them because of the transparency they're given. I really like the 2d dark color. I have searched frantically and have found NOTHING about this.
I have used confity, compiz (with extra plugins), gconf-editor, and searched for compiz rules. Nothing.

EDIT: I understand that you can edit the top panel's opacity with compiz settings manager, but I haven't found a way to do this for the Dock/Launcher alone.

Comment: I tried it some time ago, but actually it's impossible. Hope it change!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33043/can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-transparency), you can adjust the background opacity if you use unity-df.