# Ubuntu 12.04 Unity Chameleon vs 12.10

Tags: unity

In 12.04 Ubuntu when I change wallpaper only left bar changes.
If I set white wallpaper it gets pretty ugly:
[image]

While for other colors it's okay:
[image]

In Ubuntu 12.10 I remember that top panel colors changes aswell. How do I make it change in Ubuntu 12.04 aswell? (I had to go from 12.10 to 12.04 ubuntu since it didnt have drivers for my video adapter, and I was too dumb to install them properly since it's Nvidia).

Questions:

1. Is top panel color changing only in 12.10?
2. Why is left panel grey and not-matching at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top panel doesn't automatically change color, and it's never been "chameleonic" by default. What you can do however is adjust the transparency of the panel to let some of the wallpaper come through and have it match the launcher:

- [How can I adjust the transparency of the Status Bar (top panel)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70910/how-can-i-adjust-the-transparency-of-the-top-panel)

You can also tweak the Launcher's transparency:

- [Can I change the Unity Launcher transparency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33043/can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-transparency)

The reason it looks "ugly" is because it's a white background and it matches the best it can given an all white background, which ends up being a gray color. There's no real fix to that other than adjusting the transparency or using another background.

Comment: Thank you! However I am 100% sure that top panel changes color in 12.10 by default

Comment: or not...damn, I need to sleep more >< Tell me please, does top panel change color in Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.